# Difference between Turkish and Greek coffee?

Tags: turkish-coffee

Is there a difference between Turkish and Greek coffee? Or is it the same thing with different names at different places?

Comment: I have only anecdotic evidence for this so I won't make it an answer, but Turks traditionally boil the coffee three times, while I've always seen Greek people boiling it only once. I've also found that ordering a γλυκό coffee in Greece will get you something sweeter than ordering a çok şekerli coffee in Turkey.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

...also called Arabic, Cypriot, Bosnian, and what not -- it is the same method.

In Greece, it's become *Greek coffee* (along with the former "Turkish" *Greek delight*) after conflicting with Turkey and the 1974 invasion of Cyprus.

The method itself (boiling finely ground coffee in copper cezve, typically sweetened, and served in a demitasse) is said to stem from 15th century Yemen, reaching Constantinople in 17th century and consequently spreading across Ottoman Empire.

Apparently, there are interesting variations to it. For instance, *Syrian coffee* (and probably some others) is flavoured by cardamom.

Comment: Thinking of _hot dogs_ and _freedom fries_, I wonder which of the many such was the earliest one.

Comment: -1 Arabic coffee is not the same thing as Turkish coffee.

Answer (score 4):

Please do not confuse Arabic coffee with Turkish coffee.

Arabic coffee, called *gahwah* is something completely different than Turkish coffee ... which is called Turkish coffee in the Middle East.

It has completely different coloration and is also served differently. It is also not sweet.

[Wikipedia explains it thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_coffee):

> Arabic coffee, or ‘‘Al-Qahwa’’ (Arabic: قهوة‎, qahwah, locally gahwah
>   or g'hawah), is made from coffee beans roasted very lightly or heavily
>   from 165 °C (329 °F) to 210 °C (410 °F) and cardamom, and is a
>   traditional beverage in Arabian culture. Traditionally, it is roasted
>   on the premises (at home or for special occasions), ground, brewed and
>   served in front of guests. It is often served with dates, dried fruit,
>   candied fruit or nuts. This brewing method is common in Najd and
>   Hijaz, and sometimes other spices like saffron (to give it a golden
>   color), cloves, and cinnamon. Some people add a little evaporated milk
>   to slightly alter its color; however, this is rare. It is served from
>   a special coffee pot called dallah (Arabic: دلة‎) and the coffee cups
>   are small with no handle called fenjan. The portions are small,
>   covering just the bottom of the cup.

It looks like this:

[image]

Turkish coffee, on the other hand:

[image]

Comment: this is already mentioned by hoc_age in a duplicate question @ http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/coffee-in-jordan-vs-turkish-coffee

Comment: Dear Burhan, the arabic coffee in syria and lebanon and jordan is called kahwa mura , and it is darker than the gulf one and even stronger.

Comment: and the Turkish coffee also called just kahwa

Answer (score 1):

It has always been Arabic. However, the World met the coffee you mentioned through Ottoman Empire, a Turkish country. It became Turkish Coffee. Some Turkish stuff is known as Greek too. Let me say, Turkish/Greek delight, Turkish/Greek yoghurt and Turkish/Greek coffee.

Answer (score 1):

To me they are identical except for the variations inherent to the coffee used to brew it. Here is an example of Greek coffee, note the coffee looks almost like chocolate:
[image]