# Coffee in Jordan vs Turkish coffee

Tags: turkish-coffee

These two coffees look the same to me - is there any difference? I didn't get a chance to taste the coffee while I was in Jordan, which is why I'm still curious. Thanks!

Comment: There's quite a thorough answer (and a bit of debate!) about the subject at a similar question [about Greek vs. Turkish coffees](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/483). In sum, the style of coffee is common throughout the region, with some local differences. Does that answer your question in general? Or, hopefully someone who knows of Jordanian coffee will answer.

Comment: ah, missed that somehow. Looks like it falls under the umbrella of "Arabic coffee." Thanks :)

Comment: You're talking about the dark-hued style of [Arabic coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_coffee); there's also a light-hued style, sometimes called ["Saudi style"--one recipe here](http://www.yasalamcooking.com/saudi-coffee/), which is made from very lightly-roasted beans. Anyway, I'll close this as duplicate. Glad you have your answer.

Comment: Also, remember to [@-mention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) the user to whom you're replying in a comment so it's clear and so they get a notification in their SE inbox. Though it wasn't necessary in this case for me to do (person who posted the commented-on question/answer always gets notified). More at the [help] on fun features like this. Welcome (again) to [se]!